# Python : why does the words go to the next line when I use \t and not space character?

Tags: python

Question : python v 3.9.4 print question.
why does the print the following the last word (SINCE)  goes to the next line, but if I use space instead (same number of characters in a line), everything prints on the same line ?!

Is there a number of characters per line defined someplace ?!

```
print('TAB  :ClusterOperator \t\t VERSION \t AVAILABLE \t PROGRESSING \t DEGRADED\t SINCE')

print()
print('NOTAB:ClusterOperator                  VERSION         AVAILABLE       PROGRESSING    DEGRADED SINCE" )
```

OutPut:

```
111111111-111111111-111111111-111111111-111111111-111111111-111111111-111111111-111111111-111111111 <added to could the # of charecctors> 

TAB  :ClusterOperator            VERSION         AVAILABLE       PROGRESSING    DEGRADED
SINCE

NOTAB:ClusterOperator                  VERSION         AVAILABLE       PROGRESSING    DEGRADED SINCE
```

Comment: Search for "tab stop". The tab advances to the next tab stop (column). If the *column* overflows in the terminal/console, then wrapping occurs. The number of characters used to move the virtual cursor to the column doesn't matter.

Comment: How output from `print` gets displayed on your screen depends on your console, not on Python. Are you running this code from the command line (if so, which OS)? Or are you running it within some IDE with its own terminal emulator?